# Express - Authenticating URI endpoints using facebook & Google

Tags: authentication, express

I've got URI endpoint authentication working for both facebook & google in my express app through separate middlewares. Facebook uses passport facebook-token strategy, whereas for google I wrote my own middleware using nodejs client lib for google API. What I want is to authenticate a user on a URI endpoint using both these middleware.

```
/*
//google controller file
module.exports = function(req,res,next){

}
*/
googlectrl = require('google controller file');
//this works fine
app.get('someurl',googlectrl,function(req,res){
//google user authenticated
}

//this works fine too
app.get('someurl',passport.authenticate('facebook-token',{session=false}),function(req,res){
//google user authenticated
}
```

But how do I combine the two for the same uri. Otherwise I need to use seperate URI for google & fb. Pls advice. Pls note I've tried implementing google strategy and it has not worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one array field for your user object named as providers as shown below:

```
{
  "name": "asdasd",
  "providers": [ 'google']
}
```

And at server side check user is using which provider and call the method accordingly. For example:

If a user requests with google service provider then call

```
function handleGoogleAuthentication(){
   // Logic 
}
```

And if a user requests with facebook service provider then call

```
function handleFacebookAuthentication(){
     //Logic
}
```

Comment: The issue in doing that is express middleware requires to be in this format function(req,res,next){} and I also need to pass passport object in order to authenticate using facebook-token strategy like passport.authenticate('facebook'..). But it doesn't allow it. The other option I have is create seperate URI endpoints for both google & fb and route the requests separately based on what user signs in - facebook,google